# Changing rgb percentage color values with hexadecimal ones in a svg file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to swap out all rgb(0%,0%,0%) to hex values inside a svg because the software I use doesn't support rgb values. I have figured out I can use [webcolors](http://webcolors.readthedocs.io/en/1.5/contents.html#webcolors.rgb_percent_to_hex) to achieve the conversion. And I'm now trying to use re.sub to find the rgb values line-by-line and substitute them with hex using webcolors with the following exp:

`exp = r'rgb\((?:(?P<red>\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50})?)(?:\%\,?)(?P<green>\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50})?)(?:\%\,?)(?P<blue>\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50})?)(?:\%))\)'`

However, I get value error whatever I try. Here is the code:

```py
import re
from webcolors import rgb_percent_to_hex

exp = r'rgb\((?:(?P<red>\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50})?)(?:\%\,?)(?P<green>\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50})?)(?:\%\,?)(?P<blue>\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50})?)(?:\%))\)'

with open('sample.svg', 'w') as f:
    for line in f:
        re.sub(exp, rgb_percent_to_hex(r'\g<red>', 
                                       r'\g<green>', 
                                       r'\g<blue>'), line))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot run functions the way I initially thought with `re.sub`.
I managed it in the following way (here with a folder of svgs):

Setup

```py
import re
import os
from webcolors import rgb_percent_to_hex

path = 'path/to/svgs'

# function that return hex color values from rgb
def cs(s): return rgb_percent_to_hex((s.group(1), s.group(2), s.group(3)))

# cobble up the svg files
svg_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.svg')]

# There are probably more readable ones than this reg ex
```

`exp = r'rgb\((?:(\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50}\%)?)(?:\,?)(\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50}\%)?)(?:\,?)(\d{1,3}.?(?:\d{1,50}\%)?)(?:))\)'`

Then

```py
# walking the files and making the change
for j in scaled_files:
    w = open(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(path, j))[0] + '_sub.svg', 'w')
    r = open(os.path.join(path, j))
    for l in r:
        w.write(re.sub(exp, cs, l))
    w.close()
    r.close()
```

You can just as easily do this with a single file with a few small changes.